# loading circle/image on div using css

Tags: css, jsni

I want to show a moving loading circle or some image with text"loading", it must be displayed on click of the save button of form. It must stay on the form till the values are going from client side to server side.

I have my form code in jsni.

help me with the css of it that how can i add the effect to the div of the form.

Comment: A gif image? http://preloaders.net/

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle with what you've got so far?

Comment: i have just grey out the screen by css, and code is too lengthy too show. I have to apply all this jsni. my jsni code is in ui binder java class.

Comment: can be a simple animated image as we see on some websites during the page load or saving of the form.